# what is the force that holds together like charges in capacitor, battery

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

I was wondering what force holds together like charges in a capacitor or battery.

For instance, in a capacitor there are two oppositely charged plates. What holds together the electrons in one plate, and similarly what holds the protons together in the other plate (since like charges repel)?

Comment: Nothing holds them together. They don't go anywhere because they **can't** go anywhere. A capacitor in a circuit is continuously charged and discharged.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the conductivity of the surrounding materials.

Charge can move freely around on the metallic capacitor plates due to their 
 high conductivity. It can **not** move freely into the air due to its very low conductivity. The repulsion between equal-signed charges is *less* than the resistance of the air. So, although they are strongly repelled from each other, they are more strongly "repelled" from the air. The charge repulsion is a "push", while the air is a "wall".

But add enough charge to a capacitor plate and their repulsion **will** overcome the air resistance at some point. The "push" will break through the "wall". Then charges **will** flow through the air directly to the other plate, in the form of sparks. Lightning during thunderstorms is the same large-scale phenomenon.

This is called **dielectric breakdown**, with the air being the **dielectric**. Any insulating material (called a dielectric when placed between capacitor plates) has a breakdown point where it cannot resist anymore.

Replacing air with another insulating material with another point of breakdown will therefore allow more charges to be accumulated before breakdown happens - corresponding to an increase in capacitance (increased charge "storage" ability).